# How to match pairs of variables

Tags: javascript, operators

I have three urls I have split down to keywords. In JavaScript I want to see if two of these Urls match two given keywords. Both keywords have to match two of the url's for the code to proceed but I can't think of a short way to do it.

I have tried...

```
if (url1 || url2 || url3 === "keyword1" && "keyword2") {
....
}
```

And

```
if (url1 || url2 || url3 === "keyword1" && url1 || url2 || url3 == "keyword2") {
    ....
    }
```

This is as far as I got. The problem is, it returns a match for just one of the keywords instead of only returning a match for both . I have a feeling that not ruling out the first match is causing the second to match the same variable. I hope this makes sense!

Can anybody help me?

Comment: You mean `keyword1` and `keyword2` must appear in any of the three urls?

Comment: @Jack yes, that's right. One keyword in one of the three Urls. And the other keyword in one of the remaining two Urls.

Comment: Right, do you need to know which variables contained the keywords though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you combine all url values into a single array you can use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (the page includes a compatible version if a browser doesn't support this relatively new method).

```
var urls = [url1, url2, url3];

if (urls.indexOf('keyword1') >= 0 && urls.indexOf('keyword2') >= 0) {
    // both keywords are in there somewhere
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jack I haven't tested this one but I am pretty sure it's the same as Kevin so thank you for helping me out :)

Comment: OK I have changed the appointed answer, based on my experience that var works, whereas array may not work cross browser, and that the answer worked and was short hand I as wanted. As I was pleased with so many quick answers I have also taken into account the speed of the replies!

Answer (score 2):

`||` and `&&` are logical operators. You can not use strings for their operands(meaningfully).

You will have to individually check every url match and do logical operation on the result. Also, you should use `()` to not mess with operator precedence.

Try something like:

```
[url1, url2, url3].indexOf("keyword1") != -1 && [url1, url2, url3].indexOf("keyword2") != -1
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the function `indexOf()`.

```
array = [url1, url2, url3]
if(array.indexOf("keyword1") >= 0 && array.indexOf("keyword2") >= 0) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: OK thanks everyone! I'll work through all your answers and let you all know what worked :)

Comment: Thanks @Kevin I tried this one out first and it was perfect! Thanks ever so much!

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please upvote it and any other helpful answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is the shortest way I can think of:

```
switch("keyword1") {
  case url1: case url2: case url3:
    switch("keyword2") {
      case url1: case url2: case url3:
        // success! rest of code here
    }
}
```

If you polyfill Array.prototype.indexOf, you can just use:

```
var urls = [url1,url2,url3];
if( urls.indexOf("keyword1") > -1 && urls.indexOf("keyword2") > -1) {
    // ok!
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Kolink and everyone for their varied array of solutions. You saved this girl another 24 hours of headache

Answer (score 1):

```
var urls     = [url1, url2, url3], 
    keywords = ["keyword1", "keyword2"],
    match1   = 0,
    match2   = 0;

for (i=urls.length; i--;) {
   if (urls[i].indexOf(keywords[0]) != -1) {
       match1 = i;
   }else if (urls[i].indexOf(keywords[1]) != -1) {
       match2 = i;
   }
}

if (match1 && match2) {
    //urls[match1] //contains url matched to keyword1
    //urls[match2] //contains url matched to keyword2
}
```

without `array.indexOf` ?

Answer (score 0):

edit:

a complete solution:

```
var urls = ['http://google.com', 'http://yahoo.com'];
var keywords = ['oo', 'com'];

var matches = [];
var i;
for (i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

    var j;
    var matched = true;
    for (j = 0; j < keywords.length; j++) {
        matched = matched && urls[i].indexOf(keywords[j]) !== -1;
    }

    if (matched) {
        matches.push(urls[i]);
    }
}
```

the matches array then contains the urls that match the given keywords

Comment: `url1 == "keyword1" && url1 == "keyword2"` ... isn't that, like, always false?

Comment: That is true if all three urls matches any of the keywords, not if two of the urls matches keywords.

Answer (score 0):

There is no multiple match shorthand, you have to write out the conditons, and match the different combinations:

```
if (
  (url1 === "keyword1" && url2 === "keyword2") ||
  (url1 === "keyword1" && url3 === "keyword2") ||
  (url2 === "keyword1" && url3 === "keyword2") ||
  (url1 === "keyword2" && url2 === "keyword1") ||
  (url1 === "keyword2" && url3 === "keyword1") ||
  (url2 === "keyword2" && url3 === "keyword1")
) {
  ...
}
```